# SUM based on product name per day

Tags: mysql, sql, group-by, sum

I have a table such as this:

```
Day         Product  Volume
----------------------------
2019-01-01 | A      |  100
2019-01-01 | B      |  200
2019-01-01 | B      |  100
2019-01-02 | B      |  150
2019-01-02 | C      |  170
2019-01-02 | B      |  190
2019-01-03 | A      |  150
2019-01-03 | A      |  140
2019-01-04 | B      |  130
2019-01-04 | A      |  130
2019-01-04 | C      |  170
```

And I want to produce a query where for each day there is a sum of the total volumes for each product, could anyone help with this?

The expected result i would like would be something like:

```
Day         Product  Volume
----------------------------
2019-01-01 | A      |  100
2019-01-01 | B      |  450
2019-01-02 | C      |  170
2019-01-02 | B      |  190
2019-01-03 | A      |  290
2019-01-04 | B      |  130
2019-01-04 | A      |  130
2019-01-04 | C      |  170
```

many thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is basic `GROUP BY`:

```
SELECT Day, Product, SUM(Volume)
FROM MyTable
GROUP BY Day, Product
```

Comment: The problem with this is that It ended up with The product A and then all the volumes for each day, and the the product B and all the volumes for each day etc. So the days were repated for each product if that makes sense

Comment: @sam, and if you add `ORDER BY day, Product` at the end?